# Bot Framework emulator error

Tags: botframework

when I want to test my bot created with the Microsoft Bot Framework locally, I get the following error.. Does anybody know how to fix it?

[image]

The code of the bot is just the sample echo bot. 
I Followed the steps described [here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/gettingstarted.html#emulator).
Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you translate the german?

Comment: The error translated: Error while sending. Conenction was closed: Unexpected Error while sending. Handshake Failure Unexpected package format. This are the main messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get a connection to my emulator by cleaning the app ID and secret from the web.config and using http://

Answer (score 1):

1. If the request is going to local host, it make sure it's not SSL, as that typically doesn't work. (i.e. http:// vs https://)
2. Make sure the port is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the samples are listening on 3978, I see 3979 up there.  I'm assuming that's an intentional choice?

Comment: When I run the example locally it start at port 3979. When I try to connect to 3978 I get a connection error.